# How to process ISO date sting in the MongoDB mapReduce function in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I'm using the Date function in the mapReduce function in the Node.js application. In the map function below, I convert the ISO date string to the Date object first. Then get the year of the date, which will be used as the key. The expected result is the _id in the output collection is "2013". But in fact, the _id is NaN (The type is Double).

It seems that the Date function used inside the mapReduce function is different from normal JS Date function.

1. How can I use the normal JS Date function inside the map function below?
2. If it is impossible, how to process the ISO date string inside the map function?

.

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

var map = function() {
    var date = new Date("2013-03-19T08:27:58.001Z"); // Convert ISO date string to Date object
    var year = date.getFullYear(); // Get the year of the date.

    emit(year, this);
};


var reduce = function(key, values) {
    if (values.length) {
        return values[0];
    }
};

/**Connect to MongoDB
*/
var server = new mongodb.Server(dbIP, dbPort, {});
var db = new mongodb.Db(dbName, server, {safe:true});
db.open(function (err, client) {
    if( err ) {
        console.log('DB: Failed to connect the database');        
    }
    else {      
        console.log('DB: Database is connected');

        db.collection(collectionName).mapReduce(
            map,
            reduce,
            {
                out: 'map_reduce_collection'
            }
            , function (err, collection, stats){            
                if( err ) {
                    console.log('Map reduce: Fail.');        
                }
                else {      
                    console.log('Map reduce: Success.');
                }
                db.close();
        });     
    }   
});
```

=======EDIT: Add the solution=========

ISODate solves my issue. The code below works for me.

```
// The map and reduce functions are serialized by the driver and run in the MongoDB server.
// The functions used in them should be supported by the mongo shell.
// A tip is checking if a function is supported by map-reduce function by execuing it in the mongo shell.
// For example, the Date function is different from the one supported by Node.js. 
// In Node.js, the var date = new Date("2013-03-19T08:27:58.001Z"); works. But it doesn't work in mongo shell.
// So it can't be used in the map function.
var map = function() {
    var date = new ISODate("2013-03-19T08:27:58.001Z");
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    emit(year, this);
};
```

Thanks,
Jeffrey

Comment: Why don't you exchange the `new Date()` for a `new ISODate()`, the ISODate is basically a more advanced and better wrapper for date so you can use all the same functions.

Comment: FWIW, the `map` and `reduce` functions are serialized by the driver and run in the MongoDB server, hence the asymmetry.

Comment: Thank you Sammaye. The 'var date = new ISODate("2013-03-19T08:27:58.001Z");' returns the expected date object.

Comment: If you’ve solved your problem, you should either post your answer below, which you can accept after 48 hours, or, if you think your question/answer are of no relevance to future visitors, you can delete your question entirely. You should *not* simply edit your question with the solution. Or @Sammaye should add an answer themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Post the answer here.

ISODate solves my issue. The code below works for me.

```
// The map and reduce functions are serialized by the driver and run in the MongoDB server.
// The functions used in them should be supported by the mongo shell.
// A tip is checking if a function is supported by map-reduce function by execuing it in the mongo shell.
// For example, the Date function is different from the one supported by Node.js. 
// In Node.js, the var date = new Date("2013-03-19T08:27:58.001Z"); works. But it doesn't work in mongo shell.
// So it can't be used in the map function.
var map = function() {
    var date = new ISODate("2013-03-19T08:27:58.001Z");
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    emit(year, this);
};
```

Comment: Mark this as correct answer. It solved my issue too. Thank you!